# Default sorting in nattable

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

There is a requirement wherein the user wants that the Nattable be default sorted as per a specific column & in a particular direction.
The nattable is expected to contain around 300 rows.
The current implementation contains IColumnPropertyAccessor which will give the rows & the cell values at runtime.
The column as well as the direction can have any value & after the default sort, sorting must be possible on other columns as well.
We are using ISortModel for the initial sort as below (this is once the nattablle is configuered)

```
nattable.configure();
getsortHeaderLayer().getSortModel().sort(0, SortDirectionEnum.ASC, false);
```

Please suggest any other way out if any to reduce the sorting time & make the nattable more efficient.

Note :- The table is expected to have on an average 300 rows. Do let me know if more information is required.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean with reducing sorting time and make NatTable more efficient? Sorting a collection of 300 entries should be quite fast. Do you use GlazedLists or do you really sort the underlying collection?

Comment: I am using a gazedList.
I just want to know is there a better way out, some command I should use or any such.
I read that the sortcommand uses the SortModel sorting only.
So just keen to know if any other way can Nattable be sorted.
By reducing the time / efficient I mean to say that is there any other way.
I just want to double sure with this approach :-) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use GlazedLists, there is no better performance gain I would know for initial sorting inside NatTable. That should be already good enough. Whether you use the `SortColumnCommand` or directly operate on the `SortModel` is a design decision. I typically recommend to use the command, as it hides the implementation/configuration details. The default command handler uses the `ISortModel`, so in the end the same code is executed.

Comment: There is no such constraint, but since I read SortColumnCommand internally use the SortModel I thought of reducing a step or so.